# Transicion entre UITableViews sobrepone informacion de ambas vistas

Tags: swift2, swift

Estoy trabajando con `UITableView`s embebidas en un `NavController`. Sucede que cuando hago la transición de una vista a otra da la impresión de que fusiona la información de ambas vistas por unos milisegundos.

Dejo un video del comportamiento de las vistas.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4915071/Transicion.mov

¿Será este un coportamiento propio de la animación entre vistas?. ¿O debo hacer algo en mi vista A antes de pasar a la vista B para evitar esa "fusión"?. ¿Tal vez algo en el `ViewDidDissapear`?. No pongo código puesto que me pasa en todas las transiciones entre vistas.

He probado en un dispositivo real y sucede lo mismo que en el simulador.

Comment: ¿Podrías subir el proyecto a Dropbox o similar para analizarlo mejor?

Comment: @AlbertoMier Mantener ambas etiquetas permite que los usuarios que siguen la etiqueta de swift también vean esta pregunta, y se sepa que es específica para swift2

Answer (score 0):

Prueba hacer un **pushViewController** sin animación.

Answer (score 0):

En el segundo `ViewController` setea la propiedad `clipToBounds` de la `view` principal